# Checking kernel memory usage

Tags: windows, kernel, x86

How would I know the kernel memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Windows Task Manager (Ctrl-Shift-Esc, or Ctrl-Alt-Del-->Task Manager).

Not sure about previous versions of Windows off-hand (you didn't specify), but Windows 7 shows both Paged and Nonpaged kernel memory usage.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

You check it with `procexp` (Process Explorer, free tool from Sysinternals Suite), navigate in menu the following way - View -> System Information -> Memory